# Link shared library under Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I with success compile library LibXtract to shared object libxtract.so and want to use is in second project.

In mention project I try to compile it on simple function:

```
#include <com_androidnative1_NativeClass.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include "libxtract.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_androidnative1_NativeClass_showText
(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz)
{

    float mean = 0, vector[] = {.1, .2, .3, .4, -.5, -.4, -.3, -.2, -.1}, spectrum[10];
    int n, N = 9;
    float argf[4];

    argf[0] = 8000.f;
    argf[1] = XTRACT_MAGNITUDE_SPECTRUM;
    argf[2] = 0.f;
    argf[3] = 0.f;

    xtract[XTRACT_MEAN]((void *)&vector, N, 0, (void *)&mean);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "LIbXtract", "Button pushe2");
}
```

I have flat structure:

- jni/com_androidnative1_NativeClass.c
- jni/com_androidnative1_NativeClass.hjni/libxtract.h
- jni/other *.h files from libxtract interface
- jni/Android.mk
- jni/Applicatoin.mk

library libxtract.so I put in mainproject/lib folder

my Android.mk file looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_androidnative1_NativeClass.c 
LOCAL_MODULE := com_androidnative1_NativeClass
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_SHARE_LIBRARIES := libxtract
NDK_MODULE_PATH += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../lib/
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and I still got error:

```
Compile thumb  : com_androidnative1_NativeClass <= com_androidnative1_NativeClass.c
SharedLibrary  : libcom_androidnative1_NativeClass.so./obj/local/armeabi/objs/com_androidnative1_NativeClass/com_androidnative1_Nativ    eClass.o: In function `Java_com_androidnative1_NativeClass_showText':
/home/jack/Projects/AndroidNative1/jni/com_androidnative1_NativeClass.c:20: undefined reference to `xtract'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libcom_androidnative1_NativeClass.so] Error 1
```

Code came form example of LibXtract and under C++ compile without problems, any ideas?

Comment: How exactly did you compile libxtract.so? Why don't you add its compilation to same Android.mk file, so both shared libraries can built at the same time?

Comment: I compile it by adopt this solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7308682/1409501) I just to add shred library to keep it simple

Comment: This answer sounds like solving your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593987/android-ndk-linking/10615769#10615769

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link a prebuilt shared Library to an Android NDK project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870435/how-to-link-a-prebuilt-shared-library-to-an-android-ndk-project)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Android make file should be ...

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LIB_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_androidnative1_NativeClass.c 
LOCAL_MODULE := com_androidnative1_NativeClass
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
```

**LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LIB_PATH) -lxtract**

```
LOCAL_SHARE_LIBRARIES := libxtract
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Try this make file in your second project, and you can successfully build your code without having any error.

Comment: I use yours and @FooF solution, my Android.mk looks like:


    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE := libxtract
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libxtract.so
    include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LIB_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../lib/libxtract.so
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_androidnative1_NativeClass.c 
    LOCAL_MODULE := com_androidnative1_NativeClass
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LIB_PATH)
    LOCAL_SHARE_LIBRARIES := libxtract
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: and its build with success, but when I run code where I use it I got error: 
    06-04 21:58:26.504: E/AndroidRuntime(14792): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libxtract: findLibrary returned null of course I use System.loadLibrary("libxtract");

Comment: Look, use this make file in your second project after successfully building libxtract.so. And LIB_PATH should be correct. And 'LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LIB_PATH) -lxtract' should be used in your second project make file, otherwise you will get the error that you issued in above.

Comment: LOCAL_SHARE_LIBRARIES => LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES

Answer (score 3):

In the above answer all is right but exept one.

When we want to link lib we must `add -L` before `LOCAL_LDLIBS` dir as below.

```
LIB_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../lib

LOCAL_LDLIBS += **-L**$(LIB_PATH) -lxtract
```

Else it will give error as below

> cannot open XXX/../lib: Permission denied

Comment: Can you clarify which answer you are referencing?

Comment: The  syntax to include shared libraries in the search path. 1) Must specify path via -L directive and then 2)immediately afterwards the lib to be shared via the -l directive.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Android NDK build scripts about your shared library. Check `${NDK}/doc/PREBUILTS.html` for instructions how this can be done. They advise to add `Android.mk` in the same directory where you have your `libXtract.so`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libXtract
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libXtract.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Debugging tip: I guess you are using `ndk-build` to build your "second project". Try running `ndk-build` with `V=99` (try `V=99 ndk-build` or `ndk-build V=99` - my memory failing). This will show you the the exact failing linking command. You should likely have options `-lXtract` and `-L/path/to/libXtract/library`. (Sometimes it is convenient to just copy and paste the linking command to run it  manually to find the right options for successful linking, before actually fixing the build settings.)

**Update:** I now see @codetiger's comment seems to point to a same sort of answer (without mentioning the NDK document which is good reading - so I am not deleting this answer).