# Fail when I use a function of a c++ library

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am doing a native Android application and I have this problem:

In my native code I want to use Siglib (a DSP library) but when i use a function of this library and i try to run the app, appears this error:

```
undefined reference to 'SDA_CorrelateLinear'
```

This is my simple code:

nativo.cpp

```
#include "nativo.h"
#include "Parameters.h"
#include <siglib.h>

#include <android/log.h>


using namespace std;

#define LOG_TAG "NATIVO"
#define LOGD(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_sistoleaudiocapture_Processing_init_1variables(
        JNIEnv *, jclass) {

    long dir = (long) new Parameters();

    return (dir);
}

JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_sistoleaudiocapture_Processing_prueba_1nativa(
        JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong retorno) {

#define INPUT_1_LENGTH          5L
#define INPUT_2_LENGTH          5L

    SLData_t pSrc1[] = { 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25 };

    SLData_t pSrc2[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };

#define RESULT_LENGTH           ((SLArrayIndex_t)(INPUT_1_LENGTH + INPUT_2_LENGTH - 1))

    SLData_t dest[RESULT_LENGTH ];

    SDA_CorrelateLinear(pSrc1,pSrc2,dest,5,5,9);

    //SDA_CorrelateLinear(pSrc1, pSrc2, dest, INPUT_1_LENGTH, INPUT_2_LENGTH,
        //  RESULT_LENGTH );

    double m1;
    int pos_m = 0;
    double aux = 0, mayor = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        aux = dest[i];
        if (aux > mayor) {
            mayor = aux;
            pos_m = i;
        }
    }
    return (mayor);

}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)



LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := nativo.cpp Parameters.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH) C:\Users\telo\Downloads\SigLibFree\siglib\include
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl 

LOCAL_MODULE     := native_code

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

How can i do to solve this problem? Is possible if this library not have a Android version like OpenCV for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you are including the header files from SigLib, but you're not linking with it.

So to answer your last question, no, you need an Android version of SigLib's library to be able to use it in Android. Apparently, they don't have one out of the box, but it might be possible to compile it yourself (it's probably not a trivial task, but [they do claim](http://www.numerix-dsp.com/siglib.html) they have "Highly Portable ANSI C Source").

If you manage to obtain or create a SigLib library for Android, you might want to consult [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874348/link-shared-library-under-android-ndk) to see how to include it in your project.

Comment: In Siglib's folder there are two files: siglib.a and siglib.so. Can I use this files?? And if yes how be my Android.mk?  thanks

Comment: From looking in [their site](http://www.numerix-dsp.com/free/), it doesn't seem like they have it built for Android. You're probably looking at libraries that will only work on PC Linux.

Comment: yes.. I am beginner in programming and I don¡t know how build this libraty to Android, some help? Then, when I have this library compile i supose that I only have to follow the steps of the question that you propose

Comment: this is the .zip that i domwloaded https://www.dropbox.com/s/ouvnhk91qkhs7ha/SigLibFree.zip

Comment: Building this library for Android is not very different than what you already started doing (your setup actually just builds a library named `native_code` from a source file named nativo.cpp). You could actually just add all the SigLib source files directly to your Android.mk file, so they are included in your `native_code` library. The alternative is to create a separate folder, with a separate Android.mk file, and put all the SigLib sources there (and then consult the question I linked to). I'd recommend you check their license though, to make sure you are allowed to do it.

Comment: ummm.. I have just revised the license and this library not open the source code, so I will can't build it. So i will try other library.. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

First off, my apologies for not replying before now but I didn't realize there were any SigLib questions on here.
I know it has been a long time but I don't like threads that I should respond to to be left unanswered.
I'm sure you've moved on by now but I figured there is no harm in answering your question.

SigLib has been used in a number of significant Android applications so I know it is robust in this scenario. The free version of SigLib includes a build for Android.
As PaF mentioned, you do need to link the library file in addition to including the header.
There is a simple example provided that shows how to do this.

If you need any further assistance then please do not hesitate to contact me through the Numerix-DSP website.
Best regards,
John