# FFTW Build Android

Tags: android, c++, fftw

I just follow this sophisticated and nice manual

[compiling fftw3 in android ndk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201911/compiling-fftw3-in-android-ndk)

I succesfully build config.h file but in this next step with Android.mk:
 IAm stack becouse I try build this and Console says:

```
  12:53:23 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project F      ileBroswerActivity ****
 sh "C:\\Users\\Peťulka\\Desktop\\android-ndk-r5b-windows\\android-ndk-r5b\\ndk-build"         all 
Invalid attribute name: 
   package
   /c/Users/Peťulka/Desktop/GUI/FileBroswer/jni/Android.mk:2: /fftw3/project/jni/Android.mk: No such file or directory
       /c/Users/Peťulka/Desktop/GUI/FileBroswer/jni/Android.mk:2: /fftw3/project/jni/Android.mk: No such file or directory
   make.exe: *** No rule to make target `/fftw3/project/jni/Android.mk'. Stop.
```

12:53:29 Build Finished (took 6s.316ms)

But I have this ANdroid.mk file ! in this path I check my project 10 times, I dont know where i s problem.,

Comment: Looks like make doesn't know that's a make file. You'll need to setup a rule to handle .mk files. (Note, this is not a C++ problem.)

Comment: you think in the NDK for droid?