# FFTW3 with float enabled on Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, fftw

I'm trying to use the fftw3 library on Android, with float precision enabled.

I've compiled the fftw3 source code as it is explained [in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201911/compiling-fftw3-in-android-ndk/7308682#7308682)
I added the "--enable-float" as mentioned [here.](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Installation-on-Unix.html)
So i've created the fftw libraries and placed them into another Android project. I integrated them, so that i can use the library.
When i use the double methods of fftw everything works fine. But:

I tried to use the float methods of fftw, but if i try to this i get these errors:

```
Install        : libfftw3.so => libs/armeabi/libfftw3.so
Compile thumb  : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
jni/hello-jni.c: In function 'dst_test':
jni/hello-jni.c:85:15: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/hello-jni/hello-jni.o: in function dst_test:jni/hello-jni.c:85: error: undefined reference to 'fftwf_plan_r2r_1d'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libhello-jni.so] Error 1
```

My guess is, that i have done something wrong, when i integrated the library.
I did a

```
#include "api/fftw3.h"
```

in my c-File.

My Android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
# Prebuilt FFTW library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := fftw3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfftw3.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += hello-jni.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := fftw3
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

There are some fftw + android tutorial on the internet, but i couldn't find anything about integrating the "float version" of it.

Comment: Did you ever come to solving this?

Answer (score 0):

I am actually having a problem with FFTW3 as well, but slightly different.  I think the answer to your question lies in the building the package with float support.  Adding --enable-float to your ./configure command should do the trick.  After it's built, you can include it the same way that you're including fftw3, just make it fftw3f.

Good luck.