# Compiling FFTW library with Android NDK on Windows

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, static-libraries, fftw

I'm new to Android NDK development, though I keep trying to dig further into it.

I have a task to compile and include FFTW library as a **static module** (libfftw3.a) into our Android project. I know how to include it as a module in Android.mk file. The thing I don't know is how to compile it from source code ([FFTW site](http://www.fftw.org/)) particularly with Android NDK on Windows.

I have already searched at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201911/compiling-fftw3-in-android-ndk) as well as on [other sites](https://warpedtimes.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/building-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk/). All possible solutions there are applied to Linux or Mac OS; also some standalone toolchains (?) of Android NDK are being used there. Unfortunatelly I'm pretty bad at Linux and Mac commands as well as with Android NDK's standalone toolchains and C++ code refactoring.

So, could You please provide me with some working solutions to effectively build FFTW library with NDK on Windows with minimum amount of tweaks and hacks: some articles or sources are welcome.

I need to support Android down to **API 10** as well as both **armeabi** and **x86** architectures. My environment has following features:

- Windows 8.1 x64;
- Android NDK r10;
- FFTW source code v.3.3.4

Thanks in advance for any help provided!